# How can I calculate the size of a power ferrite core transformer?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, power-amplifier, ferrite, core

I'm working on an amplifier that has to drive a load with 200 W at 100 kHz.

I have a tested architecture based on wideband ferrite transformers but for 50 W and higher frequency.

My goal is to calculate the right size of the transformer to get it not too hot and prevent saturation of the core.

The output transformer has 1:3 turn ratio and is loaded into 50 ohm. The ferrite core should be a toroid of N87 material (TDK) or equivalent.
The pick current on the primary side is about 9 A and the voltage 50 V, sinusoidal.

I have to choose the correct diameter of the toroid but I have not a precise idea to do that. The datasheet says to not go above 500 mW/cc of core losses but does not explain how to calculate losses or core size to get stable operation.

Comment: `The ferrite core shoould be a toroid of N87 material (TDK) or equivalent.` why?

Comment: I needed some time to read *peak* current - *transformer, should* and explain* was easier.

Comment: You will be (core) loss limited at 100 kHz. How much that loss limit depends on your particular situation, max ambient temperature, air flow (if any) and so on, or perhaps straight up efficiency requirement. What's your limit?

Comment: N87 seems a good material for that frequency and the target application, but I can look around if there is any better material or a better core geometry. Limits are: 25 °C ambient temperature, no air cooling, only heatsink for output transistors, efficiency 60/70 %

Comment: @mtx4 okay but, why toroid? Does it have to be? Why not PQ or EE or ETD or any other shape? Remember that winding on a toroidal core is more difficult, so you may want to consider other shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: about a 3 cm cube.

---

There are two facts necessary to the design of a transformer:

1. Core area \$A_e\$.  Flux density is proportional to applied voltage, and inverse to area and frequency.  Saturation (which must be avoided for the transformer to remain linear) depends on flux density.
2. Winding area \$A_w\$.  Current density is inversely proportional to it, and power dissipation depends on current density.

These dual constraints are related by the core's geometry, such as the product and ratio of these areas, the magnetic path length and core volume (giving core loss, and with \$\mu_r\$, magnetizing inductance).

A toroid core is a ring with a toroidal shell of windings wrapped around it.

Most other core shapes use a ring of windings, with a toroidal shell of core wrapped around it.

This gives the toroid a smaller \$A_e\$ and larger \$A_w\$, and shapes like the pot core ("P"), the opposite.  Thinner and longer shapes, like EE cores with long legs (sometimes called "EEL"), can place inbetween, thus a broad range of aspect ratios are available.

Winding area also tends to be larger, simply because less area can be taken up strictly by copper: many layers of insulation are required, particularly in mains-connected transformers.  We typically adjust \$A_w\$ downward, by a "winding factor" which accounts for area taken up by the bobbin, insulation, and packing density of the windings.

Which aspect ratio of core you choose, depends on desired efficiency, available materials, and also other constraints, like leakage inductance, size/shape constraints in the end application, and parts cost.

In any case, an aspect ratio must be chosen, as it will not be constrained by relatively simple assumptions.

Given these facts, we can design a transformer as follows.

### Total Power

Allowed power dissipation is the sum of core and winding losses.

\$P_\textrm{tot} = P_\textrm{Fe} + P_\textrm{Cu}\$

The general approach to this problem is to assume a typical design (some turns primary and secondary, a core of some shape, etc.), leaving all the parameters as variables.  We start with the most general assumptions and relationships, and substitute bit by bit until we either run out of assumptions, or the design is fully constrained and the transformer size (and number of turns and size of wire) pops out.

#### Core Loss

\$P_\textrm{Fe}\$ is given by the power density and core volume:

\$P_\textrm{Fe} = p_\textrm{Fe} v_e\$

The power density must be looked up in the core material datasheet; it depends on frequency and flux density, and probably core size and shape as well. Well-behaved materials admit a reasonable approximation with the generalized Steinmetz form,

\$p_\textrm{Fe} = c F^\alpha B^\beta\$

Parameters are available in datasheets, or can be fitted to loss curves.  (Note that α = 1, β = 2 gives the ideal (linear / resistive) case.)

---

It may be worth taking one more step back and considering component temperature instead -- which depends on surface area.  Compare with power, which depends on volume.  Because of this square-cube law, very small transformers can often tolerate much higher power densities; say, for a 6 mm sized part, core loss over 1 W cm<sup>-3</sup> may be acceptable -- when temperature is the limiting consideration.

Conversely, if efficiency is the limiting consideration, power shall be given based on specified efficiency and VA utilization (not real power output!), and size doesn't matter, so long as you provide some means of sinking the heat produced.

---

Flux density depends on applied voltage, number of turns, and frequency:

\$N = \dfrac{V_\textrm{rms}}{\sqrt{2} \pi F B A_e}\$

(If this is a square-wave (class D / switching) application, replace the coefficient \$\sqrt{2} \pi \approx 4.44\$ with an even 4.  If it's a half-wave switching application (e.g. flyback, half-wave forward), replace with 2 instead -- or just calculate flux from the waveform directly.)

If we are limited to an assumed power density \$p_\textrm{Fe}\$, then B is given by the core material curves, and \$N\$ and \$A_e\$ are free variables here.

#### Winding Loss

\$P_\textrm{Cu}\$ is given by the power density and winding volume:

\$P_\textrm{Cu}\$\$ = p_\textrm{Cu} v_\textrm{Cu} \$

Power density is given by current density and material resistivity:

\$p_\textrm{Cu}\$\$ = {J_\textrm{rms}}^2 \rho_\textrm{Cu} \$

Volume is given by wire length, size, and number of turns.  It cannot be higher than the available winding area (accounting for winding factor) times mean length of turn.  We assume the winding area is filled: otherwise we are wasting capacity and a smaller core could be used.  (MLT would overestimate if less area is filled, as well.)

\$v_\textrm{Cu} = A_w W_F l_\textrm{MLT}\$

Current density is given by ampere-turns and winding area.

\$J_\textrm{rms} = \dfrac{2 N I_\textrm{rms}}{A_w W_F}\$

Note the same current is carried by both primary and secondary (actually slightly more, but we ignore magnetizing current for now), so we shall use one winding's current, and assume double the current density.  (For inductor design, do not double it.  Other configurations may require other ratios; for example, a center-tapped secondary feeding a full-wave rectifier ("FWCT" topology) delivers load current alternately, which reduces the RMS current by 70.7%, but twice the winding length is required.)

\$P_\textrm{Cu} = \dfrac{4 \rho_\textrm{Cu} N^2 {I_\textrm{rms}}^2 l_\textrm{MLT}}{A_w W_F}\$

Note that the winding doesn't *have to* be copper, but as it's the most common case, it's commonly used to name the variables.  Likewise "Fe" (iron) for core-related variables, though we might not be using cores with a whole lot of iron in them (ferrite is, what, about 40%?).

#### Putting It Together

\$P_\textrm{tot} = P_\textrm{Fe} + P_\textrm{Cu}\$

\$\qquad = c F^\alpha B^\beta v_e + \dfrac{2 \rho_\textrm{Cu} {V_\textrm{rms}}^2 {I_\textrm{rms}}^2 l_\textrm{MLT}}{\pi^2 F^2 B^2 {A_e}^2 A_w W_F}\$

It's a... just a big pile of parameters, really.  Lacking a relationship between \$v_e\$, \$A_e\$, \$A_w\$ and so on, there isn't really much more to say, at least not precisely.

As for hand-waving approximations, perhaps we take \$l_e / l_\textrm{MLT} \approx 1\$ (real parts vary give or take a factor of 2 or so).  \$l_e\$ doesn't appear in any of these relations yet, but this is still useful because \$v_e = l_e A_e\$ (or very close for every part I've seen).  We might further relate \$l_e\$ to the overall length scale of the core.

We might also take \$A_e / A_w \approx 1\$, which is a poorer assumption (real parts vary give or take a factor of 4 or so); it would be better to use this ratio as a parameter, setting it constant across a series of parts in a given geometry.

We might also try to put it in terms of the area product \$A_e A_w\$, which is often listed in catalogs.

We can also solve for, say, B at P minima, i.e. the minimum loss design for a given core geometry -- assuming the generalized Steinmetz loss formula holds.

But at this point, it's best to begin collecting core parameters in a spreadsheet, and simply ranking them by acceptable dissipation.

---

As for a worked example, consider Ferroxcube TX42/26/13: \$A_e\$ = 95.8 mm<sup>2</sup>, \$l_e\$ = 103 mm.  Your requirement is 100kHz, 200W into 50Ω, 1:3 ratio.

Taking a typical current density J = 5 A mm<sup>-2</sup>, and core loss 1.1W at 100kHz, B = 100mT, we get:

200W into 50Ω: 100V, 2A (secondary referred; primary will be 33V, 6A)

Wire area: 2 / 5 = 0.4 mm<sup>2</sup>

Litz is recommended to minimize AC resistance.  At 100kHz, I would recommend finer than 0.2mm dia.  Say 0.14mm (≈ 35 AWG): this has 0.0154 mm<sup>2</sup> area per strand, so 26 strands are required.  (30 to 50 strands × 0.1mm dia. is commonly available and would be just fine here.  Triple it up for the primary winding.)

Turns: \$N = \dfrac{(100\,\textrm{V})}{4.44 (0.1\,\textrm{T}) (95.8\,\textrm{mm}^2) (0.1\,\textrm{MHz})}\$ = 23.5t

Pick 24, the nearest multiple of 3.  Primary is then 8 turns.

Supposing MLT = 60mm for this part (I don't have an exact figure handy), and using 22µΩmm for copper resistivity, it would dissipate about 0.63W.

This is probably a somewhat conservative pick, and maybe more like a TX36/23/10 would be adequate.

For single block windings (evenly spread around the toroid, with no interleaving or TLT-style pairing), expect somewhat over 1µH leakage inductance, and a self-resonant frequency in the 50-100MHz ballpark.  Bandwidth can be extended by using litz pairs in a "star quad" type transmission line, to construct a Ruthroff type TLT.  Also, if it can be an autoformer rather than an isolation transformer, still more bandwidth extension is possible.

Comment: Can you give definitions for the terms with units, e.g., \$A_e\$: Effective core area [\$m^2\$]. Thanks.